# How to copy a file using Copy-Item and overwrite the file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I wan to copy a file using `Copy-Item` and overwrite it. But it returns me an error.

> Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item with itself

```
$folder = "C:\XX"
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "$folder\*.txt"
$count = 1
$Get = Get-Random -InputObject $file-Count $count | Where-Object LastWriteTime

$CopyFile = Copy-Item $Get -Destination "$folder" -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: As the error says you’re trying to copy a file over itself. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I want to overwrite the file, then I can modify the file.

Comment: Why do you want to copy a file over itself?

Comment: Because I access the file in the server and I can not modify it directly.

Comment: Why do you think copying the file *over itself* would make it modifyable? Copying it to some other location might work.

Comment: If I copy it to other location and modify it, I still have the previous file in the folder.

Comment: Copying it over itself still won’t change permissions. Talk to the administrator about getting permission to modify the files.

Comment: Hi @SamiKuhmonen, I updated my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/57489190/11076819
If you don't mind, please help me to solve it. Thank you so much

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? You cannot grant yourself permissions on a file by replacing the file with a copy of itself. That would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Ya, that's why I updated my question and I put and execute my script on the server, so I don't need any permission anymore. My problem is how to mapping the file and remove it as my updated question.