# How to using loop to find a file and remove it using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some folder containing many files. I want to check whether the file exists in those folders.
If the file exists in some folder, it means I a have duplicate file in the folder. The duplicate file is not fully the same name, but I can identify from part of the file name.
Once I identify the file name, I will remove one of them.

I tried this, I can identify which folder contains the file that I want. But I do not know how to remove it.

```
$Path = ".\Folder"
$Path_File = (Get-Item (Get-ChildItem "$Path\*\*.pro")).Directory.FullName
$Path_File
$GetFilePro = Get-ChildItem -Name $Path_File -Filter *.pro*
$SubFile = $GetFilePro.Substring(7, 35)
$SubFile
$GetDupFile = Get-ChildItem -Name $Path_File -Filter *.que* |
              Where-Object {$_.Contains("$SubFile")}
$GetDupFile
Remove-Item $GetDupFile
```

### Updated

```
$FindJobpros = Get-ChildItem -Name "$OpJob_Path\*\*.pro\"
    ForEach ($FindJobpro in $FindJobpros)
    {
        $SubFile = $FindJobpros.Substring(7, 35)
        $GetDupFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $OpJob_Path\*\*.que | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match "$SubFile"}
        Remove-Item $GetDupFile
    }

}
```

#### Updated

```
for(;;)
{
[xml]$Config_File = Get-Content .\Config.xml

Function Remove_Jobpro
{
    $FindJobpros = Get-ChildItem -Name "$OpJob_Path\*\*.pro\"
    Write-Output "Job.pro : $FindJobpros"
    $SubFile = $FindJobpros.Substring(7, 35)
    # $FilterJob = Get-ChildItem -path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.que" -Filter *$sub*
    foreach($sub in $SubFile)
        {
            $n = 0
            While (-not(Get-ChildItem -path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.que" -Filter *$sub*)){
                Start-Sleep -s 5
                $n++
                (Get-ChildItem -path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.que" -Filter *$sub*)
                Write-Output "Attempt no $n"
            }
            Write-Output "Job  match found after $n attempts"
            $GetMatch = Get-ChildItem -path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.que" -Filter *$sub*
            $GetMatch
            Remove-Item $GetMatch
        }
}

Function Check_Jobpro
{
    $OpJob_Path = "D:\Auto\"
    $n = 0
    while (-not (Test-Path -Path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.pro\")) {
        Start-Sleep -s 5
        $n++
        (Test-Path -Path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.pro\")
        Write-Output "Attempt no $n"
    }
    Write-Output "Job.pro found after $n attempts"
    Write-Output "Continue to delete the file"
    Remove_Jobpro

}

$Flag_Path = $Config_File.Automation_Config.Path.Flag_Path
if(Test-Path -Path "$Flag_Path\*.XML")
{
    Write-Host "Flag Found"
    $Flag = Get-ChildItem -Name "$Flag_Path\*.XML"
    $FlagName = $Flag.ToString().Substring(0,14)
    $FlagName
    Copy-Item "$Flag_Path\*.XML" -Destination "$Flag_Path\$FlagName.PRO"
    Copy-Item "$Flag_Path\*.XML" -Destination "$Flag_Path\$FlagName.PRO"
    Remove-Item "$Flag_Path\*.XML"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Flag not found, continue delete duplicate job"
    Write-Output "Check .pro file in all folder"
    Check_Jobpro

}
}
```

Sample files

```
20110813055741_XX_ABC11AABCDEFGH_X1.que
SN_IDC_20110813055741_XX_ABC11AABCDEFGH_X1.pro
```

If found, I will remove this one `20110813055741_XX_ABC11AABCDEFGH_X1.que`

Comment: remove-item doesn't remove the duplicate file?

Comment: No, It can't. because I can not get the value of `$GetDupFile`

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot get the value of `$GetDupFile`"? Is the variable empty (i.e. you don't have a match)? Please elaborate on what you expect the code to do, and what it actually does.

Comment: Ya, I can not match it. I have a match file, but the structure how I match it might not correct.

Comment: When more files with the given extension are found, `Get-ChildItem` returns an array, so you need to loop through the found file collection. Also, PowerShell adds a property `BaseName` to the returned FileInfo objects. I'd suggest you use that too.

Comment: @Theo, I updated my code, but it still return some error. Could you please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add some examples of the file names, so I have some idea what you compare to using the `Substring(7, 35)`

Comment: Hi @Theo, I updated my code, I have a problem in the `Function Remove_Jobpro` I want to do looping to check the file. for the example of the file i updated as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code puzzles me sometimes, I *think* this is what you want to do.

1. get a list of files with the .pro extension
2. try and find .que files with a similar name (same BaseName as the .pro files excluding the first 7 characters)
3. if .que files were found that comply with that, remove them

A new requirement seems to be the part where you want to Rename .xml files, found in a folder read from a configuration file. As this was not in your original question, I won't go into that too deep.

```
$OpJob_Path  = "D:\Auto\"     #"# the root folder where .pro and .que files should be
$MaxAttempts = 5

#first try and get an array of .pro filenames without extension and having the first 7 characters stripped off
$n = 0
while ($true) {
    $n++
    Write-Host "Attempt no $n finding .pro files"
    $ProFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $OpJob_Path -Filter '*.pro' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName.Substring(7) })
    # exit the endless loop if we found .pro files OR the number of attempts have reached the maximum
    if ($ProFiles.Count -gt 0 -or $n -gt $MaxAttempts) { break }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

if ($ProFiles.Count) {
    # next, try and find .que files where the BaseName can be found in the $ProFiles array
    $n = 0
    while ($true) {
        $n++
        Write-Host "Attempt no $n finding .que files"
        $QueFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $OpJob_Path -Filter '*.que' -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $ProFiles -contains $_.BaseName })
        # exit the endless loop if we found .que files OR the number of attempts have reached the maximum
        if ($QueFiles.Count -gt 0 -or $n -gt $MaxAttempts) { break }

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    } 

    # if .que files with similar names were found, remove them
    if ($QueFiles.Count) {
        Write-Host "Job  match files found after $n attempts"
        foreach ($que in $QueFiles) { 
            Write-Host "Removing file '$($que.FullName)'"
            $que | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No Job match files (.QUE) found after $n attempts.."
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "No Job files (.PRO) found after $n attempts.."
}
```

Then there is the XML stuff in your code and if I understand that correctly, it is all about Renaming xml files into .Pro files.

To do that, I think this would be easier:

```
[xml]$Config_File = Get-Content .\Config.xml
$Flag_Path = $Config_File.Automation_Config.Path.Flag_Path
if (Test-Path -Path $Flag_Path) {
    Write-Host "Flag Found"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Flag_Path -Filter '*.xml' -File | ForEach-Object {
        $newName = '{0}.pro' -f ($_.BaseName.Substring(0,14))
        Write-Host "Renaming file '$($_.FullName)' to '$newName'"
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Flag not found."
}
```

**Note:** On both the `Remove-Item` aswell as the `Rename-Item` cmdlets, I have added a `-WhatIf` switch. With that switch, nothing gets removed or renamed. PowerShell displays what WOULD happen, so you can check first if that is what you expect.

If you are satisfied with that output, remove the `WhatIf` switches from the code so the files will get deleted and/or renamed.